# building opencv with sfm module issues

Tags: opencv, cmake, vtk, opencv-contrib, ceres-solver

I am trying to build opencv with sfm modules I've built and installed gflags then glog and the ceres-solver. Yet the make logs says: *Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Glog/Gflags*. Even though in earlier lines it says it finds both to these directories.

I've also built and installed VTK though for some reason it doesn't find it even when I manually select the build directory.

**Below is the relevant section of my CMake log:**

*VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file*

*OpenCV Python: during development append to PYTHONPATH: C:/DEV/opencv-4.2.0/builds/python_loader*

*Caffe:   NO*

*Protobuf:   NO*

*Glog:   YES*

*freetype2:   NO*

*harfbuzz:    NO*

*Module opencv_ovis disabled because OGRE3D was not found*

*No preference for use of exported gflags CMake configuration set, and no hints for include/library directories provided. Defaulting to preferring an installed/exported gflags CMake configuration if available.*

*Found installed version of gflags: C:/Program Files (x86)/gflags/lib/cmake/gflags*

*Detected gflags version: 2.2.2*

*Checking SFM deps... FALSE*

*Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Glog/Gflags*

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the SFM module to compile finally. I am not 100% on what fixed it but here is what I did: I deleted all versions of gflags, glog, and ceres-solver. I downloaded a slightly older version of ceres-solver (1.14) and VTK (8.2.0). The earlier versions might be related to using opencv4.2 and python 3.7.

I placed gflags and glog in the ceres-solver folder with eigen. Then using CMake and visual studio 2019 I built and installed gflags in debug and release. glog (linking to gflags) only in release. Finally, I built and installed ceres-solver linking to glog, gflags and eigen. Following this tutorial: http://sylvain.duchene.im/how-to-build-ceres-under-windows/

Then when I used CMake to build openCV4.2 with the contribs libraries I found both the sfm module and VTK.